# Sql Command :) Need Explain

Tags: sql, database

im New in SOF :)
i Have Question

how can when im creating Table in sql i combine 2 column in one column Like :

```
ID
Number1 
Number2
Total ( Number1 + Number2 )
```

i can do it with query can i do it when im creating Table thnx :)
Because i Need to be in table like value Lime MSAccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a computed column

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
   (
      ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
      , QtyAvailable smallint
      , UnitPrice money
      , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
    )
;
-- Insert values into the table.
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (QtyAvailable, UnitPrice)
   VALUES (25, 2.00), (10, 1.5)
;
-- Display the rows in the table.
SELECT ProductID, QtyAvailable, UnitPrice, InventoryValue
FROM dbo.Products
;
```

You can find more references [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks Man :) that is what i wana do perfect ! :)